# Background gradient repeating

Tags: css, background, gradient

I'm currently building a login page to my website and it has a linear gradient as the background. But the linear gradient is repeating.

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, grey);
  height: 400%;
  width: 400%;
}
```

How am I supposed to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `background-repeat` property with a value of `none`.

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, grey);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That works! Also, how can I have it take up the entire screen?

Comment: Updated the example with a demonstration of how to stretch the background over the entire page.